# Hiding inactive form when page reloads in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have two forms (user registration and login) in the same panel with two heading Register and login. When pressed toggles between login form and registration form. 
like this

```
<div class="panel-heading">
 <div id="register_div" >
  <a href="#" id="register_btn" class="text-center">Register</a>
 </div>
 <div id="login_div">
  <a href="#" id="login_btn" class="text-center" >Login</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And two forms like this

```
<div class="panel-body">
 <form action="/register" method = "post" id = "reg_form">
 </form>
<form action="/login" method="post" id="login_form">
</form>
</div>
```

When the page loads login form is hidden and register form is shown with javascript

```
$('#login_form').hide();
```

The problem is when login form is submitted and return login errors, The page reloads and login errors are hidden in login form and registration forms shows up by default. Now when i press the login form tab, the login errors are attached to it. How do i show login form when login error comes and same with registration form ? Full code is shared [here](https://codeshare.io/5gLNmY) for better understanding

Comment: post your controller code. you can name your error and identify in view and based on that you can show hide. for naming your error bag see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#named-error-bags

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage.

On page load you would do:

```
var formShowing = localStorage.getItem("formShowing");
if(formShowing && formShowing === "login"){
   $('#reg_form').hide();
}
else{ 
   $('#login_form').hide();
}
```

In the button clicks:

```
      localStorage.setItem("formShowing","register");
      localStorage.setItem("formShowing","login");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $errorField = $('.has-error');      //get field with error
if($errorField) {                       // if there is a field with error
    $('form').hide();                   //hide all forms first
    $errorField.closest('form').show(); //show the one with an error
} else {
    $('#login_form').hide();            //default logic
}
```